# Show that, $\arccos\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-\arccos\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)=...$

Tags: trigonometry

Where $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is the Pythagoras theorem; a,b and c are the three sides of a right angle triangle, (a,b,c) are Pythagoraean triples.

Valid only for $b>a$ and Pythagoraean triples of this type (2k+1,2k(k+1),2k(k+1)+1) (corrected by Mc cheng)

Show that,

$$\arccos\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-\arccos\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)=4\arccos\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a+c}}{\sqrt{c}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2 } }{2}\right)$$

How do I prove this identity, please help me.

I am looking through all the trigonometry section on Wikipedia and maths world but it is not helping me.

---

Maybe I could use compound angle

let $x=\arccos(a/c)$ and $y=\arccos(b/c)$

$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)$

Comment: What is the source? The degree of $a,\sqrt{a+c}$ are not same

Comment: If the triangle is $A,B,C$, the lefthand side is just $\angle B-\angle A$. It seems rather unlikely that equals the righthand side.

Comment: Strange, why there is no b on the LHS

Comment: @pisquare, As $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee, I apply a few pythogras triples and it seem to be working. It maybe only work for a few values?

Comment: @pisquare Give me an example of a pythagorean triple for which it is true.

Comment: (3,4,5), (5,12,13), (7,24,25) ,...(a,b,c)

Comment: I don't think it works for (8,15,17), (119,120,169)...

Comment: You are right, then I believe that is only valid for this type of Pythagoraean triples (3,4,5), (5,12,13),(7,24,25),(9,40,41), (2k+1,b,b+1) types.

Comment: Also b must be greater than a.

Comment: This type of Pythagorean triples can be generalised as (2k+1,2k(k+1),2k(k+1)+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $cos$ on both sides.
L.H.S.
=$\cos(\arccos(\frac{a}{c})-\arccos(\frac{b}{c}))$
=$\frac{2ab}{c^2}$

R.H.S.
=$\cos(4\arccos\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a+c}}{\sqrt{c}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2 } }{2}\right))$
=$(1-\frac{(2-\sqrt{2})(a+\sqrt{a+c})^2}{4c})^2+(\frac{a+\sqrt{a+c}}{\sqrt{c}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2 } }{2})^4-6(1-\frac{(2-\sqrt{2})(a+\sqrt{a+c})^2}{4c})(\frac{a+\sqrt{a+c}}{\sqrt{c}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2 } }{2})^2$
Sub $a=2k+1$ and $c=2k^2+2k+1$, we get:
=$\frac{4 (2 k+1) \left(\left(20-14 \sqrt{2}\right) k^3+\left(14 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{(k+1)^2}-20 \sqrt{(k+1)^2}-34 \sqrt{2}+49\right) k^2+\left(20 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{(k+1)^2}-28 \sqrt{(k+1)^2}-27 \sqrt{2}+39\right) k+\left(7 \sqrt{2}-10\right) \left(\sqrt{(k+1)^2}-1\right)\right)}{\left(2 k^2+2 k+1\right)^2}$
=$\frac{4 k (k+1) (2 k+1)}{\left(2 k^2+2 k+1\right)^2}$
=$\frac{2 (2 k+1) (2k^2+2k)}{\left(2 k^2+2 k+1\right)^2}$
=$\frac{2ab}{c^2}$

Thus,
$\arccos\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-\arccos\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)=4\arccos\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a+c}}{\sqrt{c}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2 } }{2}\right)$

Comment: wow this look huge, but anyway you have prove, thank you. I will have a look at it now.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Both $\arccos\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-\arccos\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)$ and $4\arccos(\frac{a+\sqrt{a+c}}{\sqrt{c}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2 } }{2})$ are within the range between 0 and $2\pi$. Therefore, I believe it is okay in this case.